# Erc20 Token - Convertible Tokens

Tags: erc-20

We are trying to build smart erc20 tokens to create a game system . Let me tell you what we need:

First we need to know if is it possible can you create these tokens?

Five erc20 tokens will be created. Let me call them A B C D E.

*A will be an erc20 token that will give holders airdrop B tokens daily basis ( once in 24 hour) in a rate ( for ex. for 10 A token they hold they will get 100 B tokens)

*B will be a token like ico but will work as both ico and standart token ( without a time limit) . When a user send C token to the address of B token he/she will get D in a calculated propotion.

*All token must be convertible to each other. Lets say user wants to convert A to E. He/she will send A's to a address and will get 1/2 E in return. Or send E and will get 2 A token in return in his/her address.

*As you see in ico's users send ETH and get erc20 tokens but this time we would like them to send erc20 token and receive erc20 token. And if it is possible; for a token they send they must be able to get 2 different token in return.

Is it possible? If so where can we hire a developer can do that or volunteer participant in the project?

Answer (score 1):

> First we need to know if is it possible can you create these tokens?

Yes.

> Five erc20 tokens will be created. Let me call them A B C D E.

Make five different contracts with cross functionality. Doing so is difficult. Hence use an intermediate, eg: 5 token contract and one intermediate contract that acts as an interface. If you know network topologies then create a star topology not a mesh.

> *A will be an erc20 token that will give holders airdrop B tokens daily basis ( once in 24 hour) in a rate ( for ex. for 10 A token they hold they will get 100 B tokens)

You need to call the contract function every 24 hours, get the balances of the people holding A tokens and if it passes the condition then transfer some B tokens.

> *B will be a token like ico but will work as both ico and standart token ( without a time limit) . When a user send C token to the address of B token he/she will get D in a calculated propotion.

You can use an interface here which holds the logic for the conversion, and increments/ decrements the balance accordingly. To check if the person has enough C tokens, then use the get the balance of the person.

> *All token must be convertible to each other. Lets say user wants to convert A to E. He/she will send A's to a address and will get 1/2 E in return. Or send E and will get 2 A token in return in his/her address.

Same as above, use an intermediate contract for conversion. Add the conversion rate and increase/ decrease balances accordingly.

> *As you see in ico's users send ETH and get erc20 tokens but this time we would like them to send erc20 token and receive erc20 token. And if
>   it is possible; for a token they send they must be able to get 2
>   different token in return.

They'll still have to pay for the gas. But yes I think that this is possible, just need the right code. Use modifier, get balances, transfer amount.(for 2 different tokens call transfer function of two tokens)

I can't answer the second part of the last question.
I hope this is helpful.